# Autoit - Firebird sql Combo, Return data as csv instead of XML

Tags: sql, xml, firebird, autoit

I have been far far in some project with another person, and the project is closed to finished.

We use autoIT (which is a basic script languange)

to simulate a gaming robot robot

but it is also connected to FIREBIRD sql database
I am not sure if the SQl can only return output to XML instead of .csv

Maybe someone can answer this for me

My return as XML Shows as:    (which is not preferred because I have to massive string replace etc)

```
 <results><metadata><fields><name value="NAME" alias="NAME" type="5" size="80"       scale="0" /><name value="SETCODE" alias="SETCODE" type="5" size="8" scale="0" /><name value="NORMALBUY" alias="NORMALBUY" type="7" size="4" scale="3" /><name value="NORMALSELL" alias="NORMALSELL" type="7" size="4" scale="3" /><name value="FOILBUY" alias="FOILBUY" type="7" size="4" scale="3" /><name value="FOILSELL" alias="FOILSELL" type="7" size="4" scale="3" /><name value="RARITY" alias="RARITY" type="5" size="6" scale="0" /><name value="CARDNO" alias="CARDNO" type="5" size="6" scale="0" /><name value="NORMALMAX" alias="NORMALMAX" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="NMAXSTOCK" alias="NMAXSTOCK" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="FOILMAX" alias="FOILMAX" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="FMAXSTOCK" alias="FMAXSTOCK" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="NWISHPRIO" alias="NWISHPRIO" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="FWISHPRIO" alias="FWISHPRIO" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="NCATID" alias="NCATID" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="FCATID" alias="FCATID" type="7" size="4" scale="0" /><name value="NCHECKSUM" alias="NCHECKSUM" type="5" size="40" scale="0" /><name value="FCHECKSUM" alias="FCHECKSUM" type="5" size="40" scale="0" /><name value="REMARKS" alias="REMARKS" type="5" size="120" scale="0" /></fields></metadata><data><row num="1" ><NAME>Duty-Bound Dead                                                                 </NAME><SETCODE>M13     </SETCODE><NORMALBUY>1.e-003</NORMALBUY><NORMALSELL>4.e-003</NORMALSELL><FOILBUY>3.e-003</FOILBUY><FOILSELL>1.5e-002</FOILSELL><RARITY>C     </RARITY><CARDNO>92    </CARDNO><NORMALMAX>12</NORMALMAX><NMAXSTOCK>12</NMAXSTOCK><FOILMAX>0</FOILMAX><FMAXSTOCK>0</FMAXSTOCK><NWISHPRIO>20</NWISHPRIO><FWISHPRIO>20</FWISHPRIO><NCATID>45504</NCATID><FCATID>45505</FCATID><NCHECKSUM>3063484788-4270110158                   </NCHECKSUM><FCHECKSUM>3063484788-4041915094                   </FCHECKSUM><REMARKS>Perfect                                                                                                                 </REMARKS></row></data></results>
```

But I am only interested in my data being returned (preferable i can choose my own seperator such as ; )

```
Duty-Bound_Dead;M13;0.001;0.004;0.003;0.015;C;922;2;1;0;0;20;20;45504,45505;3063484788-4270110158;3063484788-4041915094;Perfect
```

anyone has some experience with this?

Comment: Firebird itself doesn't generate XML, so how is this result obtained?

Comment: I am using a .DLL from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fbdll4vb/ to connect to Firebird
and a Include from autoit Firebird.au3 (link is down for that)

I am just researching it myself for now and willl give update later

Comment: @mark I have been trying to get into touch with you but no luck unfortunate.

I have been researching about this subject again and for now I understand that the problem is the .DLL being used in my the link i have given. I think the .DLL i am giving is only giving XML back, so it seems I have to start looking for DLL that gives back .csv kind of type result? Do i have to research about ODBC driver or?

Comment: The readme.txt of fbdll4vb says: "The recordset returned is an XML stream.". Note that most database drivers will return a recordset, transforming to output formats like csv (and xml) falls outside of the responsibilities of a driver. You simply need a driver that queries the database, and then transform it to csv yourself.

Comment: You are completely right mark, I have Solved the problem Myself , I will write out later the code and some references to my solution, It was a bumpy ride for me to find the answers, but once I got them it was so easy <3

Answer (score 0):

I've made some searchs, completed with some experience and I got some info concernng your issue.

There is actually a Firebird SQL Lib done by "El Torro", here is the quote.
I used to work with is so I'll give you an example found on the Internet plus the Lib itself!

Here is the example :

```
#include <FireBird.au3>
Local $wer Global $h_fbDll = DllOpen("C:\bird\bin"& "\fbdll4vb20.dll")
Global $servername="192.168.0.5"
Global $sDBName="C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_1_5\bin\Zimkps.gdb"
Local $sUsername = "sysdba" Local $sPassword = "masterkey"
;_FireBird_Help($h_fbDll)
_FireBird_ConnectDatabase($h_fbDll, $servername, $sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword)
;_FireBird_About($h_fbDll)
;_FireBird_Help($h_fbDll) 
ConsoleWrite( _FireBird_ExecuteStatement($h_fbDll,"select * from tubaina"))
exit
```

There is the Lib itself :

```
include-once
;#INDEX#====================================================================
; Title .........: _FireBird.au3
; Description ...: FireBird, Interbase dll udf.
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (Eltorro) 
; ============================================================================== 

; #CURRENT# ======================================================================
;_FireBird_Check
;_FireBird_About
;_FireBird_SetDebug
;_FireBird_CreateDatabase
;_FireBird_SetPageBuffers
;_FireBird_ConnectEmbededDatabase
;_FireBird_ConnectDatabase 
;_FireBird_DisConnectDatabase
;_FireBird_ExecuteBatch
;_FireBird_ExecuteSelect 
;_FireBird_ExecuteStatement
;_FireBird_Help
; ================================================================================

; #INTERNAL_USE_ONLY# ============================================================
;__FireBird_GetBstr
; ================================================================================ 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_Check
; Description ...: Test function returns the same value given. 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_Check($iCheck)
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $iCheck - IN - 
; Return values .: Success - $iCheck 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================
Func _FireBird_Check($h_fbDll,$iCheck)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "Check", "long", $iCheck)     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_Check 

; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_About 
; Description ...: Shows about message 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_About() 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================
Func _FireBird_About($h_fbDll)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "none", "About")     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_About 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_SetDebug 
; Description ...: Turns debugging on or off 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_SetDebug($xdebug) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $fDebug - IN True or false 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================
Func _FireBird_SetDebug($h_fbDll,$fDebug)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "SetDebug", "int", $fDebug)    
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_SetDebug 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_CreateDatabase 
; Description ...: Creates a database 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_CreateDatabase($sServerName, $sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword, $iWriteMode = 1,$iDialect = 3) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $sServerName - IN - 
;                  $sDBName - IN - 
;                  $sUsername - IN - 
;                  $sPassword - IN - 
;                  $iWriteMode - IN/OPTIONAL - 
;                 $iDialect  - IN/OPTIONAL - 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: Overwrites existing database if it exists unless it is being use
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================
Func _FireBird_CreateDatabase($h_fbDll,$sServerName, $sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword, $iWriteMode, $iDialect = 3)     
    Local $tagfbCreate = "char[%d];char[%d];char[%d];char[%d]"     
    $tagfbCreate = StringFormat($tagfbCreate, StringLen($sServerName) + 1, StringLen($sDBName) + 1, StringLen($sUsername) + 1, StringLen($sPassword) + 1, $iWriteMode = 1, $iDialect = 3)     
    Local $t_fbCreate = DllStructCreate($tagfbCreate)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 1, $sServerName)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 2, $sDBName)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 3, $sUsername)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 4, $sPassword)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "CreateDatabase", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 1), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 2), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 3), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 4), "int", $iWriteMode, "int", $iDialect)     $t_fbCreate = 0     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_CreateDatabase 
; #FUNCTION# =====================================================================
; Name ..........: _FireBird_SetPageBuffers 
; Description ...: Sets the page buffers when creating a database. 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_SetPageBuffers($a) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $iSize - IN - 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================ 
Func _FireBird_SetPageBuffers($h_fbDll, $iSize)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "SetPageBuffers", "int", $iSize)     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_SetPageBuffers 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_ConnectDatabase 
; Description ...: Connect to an embeded database. 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_ConnectDatabase($sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $sDBName - IN - 
;                  $sUsername - IN - 
;                  $sPassword - IN - 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: Only dialect 3 database supported 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================ 
Func _FireBird_ConnectEmbededDatabase($h_fbDll, $sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword)     
    Local $tagfbCreate = "char[%d];char[%d];char[%d]"     
    $tagfbCreate = StringFormat($tagfbCreate, StringLen($sDBName) + 1, StringLen($sUsername) + 1, StringLen($sPassword) + 1)     
    Local $t_fbCreate = DllStructCreate($tagfbCreate)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 1, $sDBName)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 2, $sUsername)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 3, $sPassword)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "ConnectDatabase", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 1), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 2), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 3))     
    $t_fbCreate = 0     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_ConnectEmbededDatabase 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_ConnectDatabase 
; Description ...: Connect to a database. ; Syntax ........: _FireBird_ConnectDatabase($sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $sServerName - IN - 
;                  $sDBName - IN -
;                  $sUsername - IN - 
;                  $sPassword - IN - 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......:
; Remarks .......: Only dialect 3 database supported 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================ 
Func _FireBird_ConnectDatabase($h_fbDll, $sServerName, $sDBName, $sUsername, $sPassword)     
    Local $tagfbCreate = "char[%d];char[%d];char[%d];char[%d]"    
    $tagfbCreate = StringFormat($tagfbCreate, StringLen($sServerName) + 1, StringLen($sDBName) + 1, StringLen($sUsername) + 1, StringLen($sPassword) + 1)     
    Local $t_fbCreate = DllStructCreate($tagfbCreate)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 1, $sServerName)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 2, $sDBName)    
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 3, $sUsername)     
    DllStructSetData($t_fbCreate, 4, $sPassword)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "ConnectDatabase", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 1), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 2), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 3), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_fbCreate, 4))
    $t_fbCreate = 0     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_ConnectDatabase 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_DisConnectDatabase 
; Description ...: Disconnect from the database 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_DisConnectDatabase() 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================
Func _FireBird_DisConnectDatabase($h_fbDll)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "DisConnectDatabase")     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_DisConnectDatabase 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_ExecuteBatch 
; Description ...: Do a batch execution of statements 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_ExecuteBatch($sCmd) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $sCmd - IN - 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================     
Func _FireBird_ExecuteBatch($h_fbDll, $sCmd)     
    Local $t_ExeBatch = DllStructCreate("char[" & StringLen($sCmd) + 1 & "]")     
    DllStructSetData($t_ExeBatch, 1, $sCmd)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "ExecuteBatch", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_ExeBatch))     
    $t_ExeBatch = 0     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_ExecuteBatch 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_ExecuteSelect 
; Description ...: Executes an SQL query. 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_ExecuteSelect($sCmd, ByRef $sResult) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $sCmd - IN - 
;                  $sResult - IN/OUT - 
; Return values .: Success - Record count 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================     
Func _FireBird_ExecuteSelect($h_fbDll, $sCmd, ByRef $sResult)     
    Local $t_ExeSelect = DllStructCreate("char[" & StringLen($sCmd) + 1 & "];uint;uint")     
    DllStructSetData($t_ExeSelect, 1, $sCmd)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "ExecuteSelect", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_ExeSelect, 1), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_ExeSelect, 2), "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_ExeSelect, 3))     
    $sResult = __FireBird_GetBstr(DllStructGetData($t_ExeSelect, 2), DllStructGetData($t_ExeSelect, 3))     
    $t_ExeSelect = 0     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_ExecuteSelect 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_ExecuteStatement 
; Description ...: Execute an SQL statement 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_ExecuteStatement($sCmd) 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
;                  $sCmd - IN - 
; Return values .: Success - 1 
;                  Failure - 0 and @error to 1 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================     
Func _FireBird_ExecuteStatement($h_fbDll, $sCmd)     
    Local $t_ExeStatement = DllStructCreate("char[" & StringLen($sCmd) + 1 & "]")     
    DllStructSetData($t_ExeStatement, 1, $sCmd)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "int", "ExecuteStatement", "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($t_ExeStatement, 1))     
    $t_ExeStatement = 0     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_ExecuteStatement 
; #FUNCTION# ===================================================================== 
; Name ..........: _FireBird_Help 
; Description ...: Shows help dialog 
; Syntax ........: _FireBird_Help() 
; Parameters ....: $h_fbDll - Handle to firebird dll. 
; Return values .: 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; Example .......: [yes/no] 
; ================================================================================     
Func _FireBird_Help($h_fbDll)     
    Local $vRet = DllCall($h_fbDll, "none", "Help")     
    Return SetError($vRet[0] <> 0, 0, $vRet[0]) 
EndFunc   ;==>_FireBird_Help 
; #INTERNAL_USE_ONLY# ============================================================ 
; Name ..........: __FireBird_GetBstr 
; Description ...: 
; Syntax ........: __FireBird_GetBstr($ptr, $len) 
; Parameters ....: $ptr - IN - 
;                  $len - IN - 
; Return values .: 
; Author ........: Stephen Podhajecki (eltorro) 
; Modified.......: 
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......: 
; Link ..........: http://fbdll4vb.sourceforge.net/ 
; ================================================================================     
Func __FireBird_GetBstr($ptr, $len)     
    Local $t_ret = DllStructCreate("char[" & $len & "]", $ptr)     
    Local $vRet = DllStructGetData($t_ret, 1)     
    $t_ret = 0     
    ;ConsoleWrite($vRet)     
    Return $vRet 
EndFunc   ;==>__FireBird_GetBstr
```

Comment: Your answer is great and I already Have these Includes and it works as described but is there a option when I do request to my sql firebird that it returns to autoit the answer as semicolon seperated info instead of xml

Comment: Hello, I don't think so, I did myself some modifications on that library to make it fitting my needs. Are you sorted out? I was away from Stack for a while.